# Configurar connectionString usando EF Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP NET MVC5  y tengo un mini proyecto que quiero publicar en el servicio de hosting que ofrece https://somee.com el problema es que cuando publico la pagina me lanza la siguiente excepción cuando intento logearme y por ende acceder a la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema seda cuando cambio mi connectionString que tengo por defecto y trabaja de manera local por el que me proporciona somee.

Mi connectionString de manera local es:

```
<add name="RossetHotelEntities3" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CRACK81-PC;initial catalog=RossetHotel;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=francia1998;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

El que utlizo cuando intento publicar en somee es:

```
 <add name="RossetHotelEntities3" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;'workstation id=RossetHotel.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=login;pwd=password;data  source=RossetHotel.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=RossetHotel'&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

La segunda cadena de conexión que usas tiene caracteres inválidos (comillas simples '), bórralas de la cadena y ya debe funcionar.

```
<add name="RossetHotelEntities3" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.RossetHotel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;workstation id=RossetHotel.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=login;pwd=password;data  source=RossetHotel.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=RossetHotel&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Aún si es una modificación pequeña, por favor agrega el código como debería quedar según tu explicación.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo ya probé con tu ejemplo y me sigue dando el mismo error. Saludos....